# codeigniter password_verify returning false

Tags: php, codeigniter

I don't know if this is a problem with Codeigniter or not but password_verify works on my other website (which doesn't have any frameworks). However in Codeigniter password_verify always returns false, despite the password being correct. I have yet to find a solution, here is my code:

```
public function login()
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username','required|trim|max_length[50]|alpha_numeric');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','required|trim');
    if($this->form_validation->run() == false)
    {
        $data['errors'] = validation_errors();
        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('user/login',$data);
    } else {
        $username = $this->input->post('username',true);
        $password = $this->input->post('password');
        $query = $this->db
        ->select("*")
        ->from("users")
        ->where("username", $username)
        ->get();
         if($query->num_rows() != 1)  throw new UnexpectedValueException("Wrong user!");
         $row = $query->row();
        if(!password_verify($password,$row->password)) throw new UnexpectedValueException('22' . $row->password);
    }

public function register()
{
    //fields username,email,password1,password2
    // $this->load->view('templates/header');
    // $this->load->view('user/register');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username','required|max_length[50]|is_unique[users.username]|trim|alpha_numeric');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email', 'trim|required|valid_email|is_unique[users.email]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password1', 'Password', 'required|trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password2','Confirm password','required|matches[password1]');
    if($this->form_validation->run() == false)
    {
        $data['errors'] = validation_errors();
        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('user/register',$data);

    } else {
        $username = $this->input->post('username',true);
        $email = $this->input->post('email',true);
        $password = $this->input->post('password');
        if($this->user_model->create_user($username,$email,$password))
        {
            echo $password;
        }
    }
 }
```

and whenever I enter the correct password the unexpected value exception is thrown:[image: exception]

Comment: what is size of password field in database?

Comment: @Naincy varchar(100)

Comment: can you share what is password for above hash....so I can try something...

Comment: @Naincy i see where you are getting.. didn't think of that. it's asd123

Comment: please check this http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1c0664940d69847b1170e5ecf094a4a5eeda2fcb

Comment: @Naincy wow that's extremely weird.. what am i doing wrong? have any idea?

Comment: are you sure you creating hash correctly... as that code is not in your question

Comment: @Naincy yea i create the hash in the user_model in the create_user function. i do $password = password_hash($password,PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

Comment: @Naincy actually never mind i found the solution lol.. it was in the input post. i should of passed in 'password1' instead of 'password'

Comment: use PASSWORD_BCRYPT in place of PASSWORD_DEFAULT

Comment: Follow this blog, explained almost all things you really need. http://blog.codeinsect.com/password-hashing-codeigniter/

Comment: @flex_ : may be this line ```$row = $query->row()``` not returning the records you want. please try ```$query->result()```.

Comment: @kishor10d the problem was input->post('password'). it's input->post('password1') thanks for your input anyways